# How can I write TypeScript definition files that depend on another definition file?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm writing a TypeScript definition file for an existing node library which use building node module like `http` and `events.EventEmitter` as a parameter.

**my question** is how can I write a definition file for this library? I have tried to copy these modules from node.d.ts into my own definition file, but I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with `use node module as parameter` Are you refering to import definitions from another `.d.ts` file?

Comment: the library is written in vanilla js, and there is a function take events.EventEmtter as parameter like `function(emitter)` when I want to write a d.ts file for this library, I don't know how to import EventEmitter from node.d.ts, even I can import the events.EventEmtter from node.d.ts, how can I ask user to download the node.d.ts automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your module should include it's own `node.d.ts` file among your `.d.ts` file (let's call it `my_awesome_lib.d.ts`)

In your `.d.ts` file you may include the necessary types as following:

```
declare module 'my_awesome_lib' {
  import * as express from 'express'; // just as example
  import { EventEmitter } from 'events'; // here you go
  export function foo(EventEmitter e): boolean; // your function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Typings tool with a `typings.json` file to manage TypeScript definition dependencies.

See that project's [FAQ](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-write-typings-definitions)

> Start by creating a new `typings.json` file, then add dependencies as
>   normal. When you publish to GitHub, locally, alongside your package
>   (NPM or Bower) or even to your own website, someone else can reference
>   it and use it.
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "typings",
>   "main": "path/to/definition.d.ts",
>   "author": "Blake Embrey <hello@blakeembrey.com>",
>   "description": "The TypeScript definition dependency manager",
>   "dependencies": {}
> }
> ```
>
> - **main** The entry point to the definition (canonical to "main" in NPM's package.json)
> - **browser** A string or map of paths to override when
>     resolving (following the browser field specification)
> - **ambient** Denote that this definition must be installed as ambient
> - **name** The name of this definition
> - **postmessage** A message to emit to users after installation
> - **version** The semver range this definition is typed for
> - **dependencies** A map of dependencies that need installing
> - **devDependencies** A map of development dependencies that need installing
> - **ambientDependencies** A map of environment dependencies that may need installing
> - **ambientDevDependencies** A map of environment dev dependencies that may need installing